# powershell problems

Tags: powershell

I'm A share point intern who's just discovered power shell. I want to start using it right away however the problem is that I'm stuck with a windows 7 pc with power shell installed on it. So i cant install share point on it.

Is there a way that I can get the microsoft sharepoint powershell snapin separately? If so please explain to me from where and how I can do this.

If I cant find the snapin separately, is there a way that I could maybe remote connect to another pc having sharepoint server installed and then somehow get this done (through power shell)? if this is possible, again PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE tell me how!!

Comment: You can connect remotely to a server with SP and use PowerShell there,no?

Comment: Is it? how can this be done?

Comment: If you have your server with a SharePoint instance, just use a remote protocol connection to connect to it

Comment: Can you fill in a little more detail? I'm very new to powershell. Even an article will help! (+1 :D )

Comment: Can you reach the machine where SharePoint Server is installed?

Comment: Yep, I'm connected to a network

Comment: So you can just open PowerShell on that machine. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/ien-gb/library/ee806878(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint Powershell install with Sharepoint server and this not able install seperatly!
So if this is possible this is not usefull and don`t work!

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to remote server with SharePoint Powershell.
You must be connected on the remote server.
I use a remote desktop connection to the server every hours of the day.
It's the only way.

However you can install SharePoint on your Pc and use Powershell locally.

You can find the guide from this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: you mean to say it's possible to install share point on windows 7 ?

Comment: Yes. Follow the guide.

Comment: For learning powershell,  you dont need the SharePoint SnapIn.  You can still learn powershell using Windows 7 machine.  Refer to http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN/1617291080?tag=adapas02-20

Comment: True, but since I have to deal with Share point here, I'd prefer to get familiar with using share point cmdlets ASAP